# Getting Json response to array ipinfo.io

Tags: javascript

Hello I have an issue with getting users IP and location. The JSON response works however I have an issue getting it into my questions array. When ever the question popups

> "Your current location?"

it goes blank. Instead I want it to print:

> "Your located: IP address from ipinfo.io and Location. Example  ip:
>   123.123.132 Location: USA"

Or any other way to get the users IP and Location and display it as a dialog You are located: p: 123.123.132 Location: USA.

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'},
  {text: 'What is your time?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Where I am located' + (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) + 'that is the day!'},
  {text: 'What language do you speak', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to me you speak: ' + language() + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (response) + '!'},


 ];

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 5000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').text(txt));
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});

function language () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLang
}

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <img src="http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/138/377/fcc.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ffc.gif">
  <h1 class="text-center">Hello I am ZENYATTA!</h1>
  <br> <br>
  <div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Responce:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
   </div>
  </div>


  

</div>


<!-- jquery for enter key press -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/s.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `response` in the scope of `questions` so this:

```
let questions = [
  ...,
  {
    text: 'Your current location?', 
    audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', 
    response: input => 'You are located:' + (response) + '!'
  }
 ];
```

will not work.

You need to pass the response from `ipinfo.io` somehow.

When you call

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
  $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
  $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

You seem to store the response in several DOM elements so you can retrieve it from there or just display those elements.... (I don't see the in your HTML)

Or store it in a variable in the same scope of `questions`

```
let questions = ...    
let ipinfoResponse;
...

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  ipinfoResponse = response;
}, "jsonp");
```

and than use `ipinfoResponse` instead of `response` in `response: input => 'You are located:' + (ipinfoResponse) + '!'`

But notice that this way `ipinfoResponse` will be undefined until you get the response. You should probably make the call to ipinfo when needed and respond when you have the data.

Comment: Problem is IF i get the data using HTML document.write it will result in a white screen

Comment: You lost me completly

Comment: Why won't you save the response in some variable?

Comment: How do you mean save the response?

Comment: in the callback of the `$.get(...)` you receive a `response` object. Just save it in some variable that's in the scope of `questions`

Comment: Could you please provide example? I tried didn't work.

Comment: Look at my answer again. I've added a small example at the bottom.

Comment: you yourself used it as an object! look at `response.ip`, `response.city` etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the questions array, arrow function parameter is named as `input`; whereas you have used `response` in the string template. Probably i typo.

Change it as below,

{text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (`input`) + '!'},

Comment: If I use input it won't give me my IP address or location.

Comment: How does this answers your question? as you said yourself the user's input is not what you want. Either you didn't explain what you wanted properly or you just don't understand what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let questions = [
  {text:'What is your name?', audio:'music/openmind.ogg', response : input => 'Hello ' + input + '!' },
  {text:'How old are you?', response : input => 'That means you were born in ' + (2017 - input) + '.'},
  {text:'Where are you from?', audio:'music/beone.ogg', response: input => 'You are from ' + (input) + '.'},
  {text: 'Do you eat healthy?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to my data you are eating ' + (input) + ' and that is healthy!'},
  {text: 'What is your time?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Where I am located' + (new Date().toLocaleTimeString()) + 'that is the day!'},
  {text: 'What language do you speak', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'Acording to me you speak: ' + language() + '!'},
  {text: 'Your current location?', audio: 'music/becoming.ogg', response: input => 'You are located:' + (response) + '!'},


 ];

let output = $('#output'),
    input = $("#input"),
    curQuestion;

function ask() {
  let qi = Math.floor(Math.random() *  questions.length); //depending on your needs, a check could be added if it's been asked directly before or only recycle questions when all are asked
  curQuestion = questions[qi];
  setOutput(curQuestion.text);
  input.val('');
}

ask(); //first call

function respond(){
  let q = curQuestion;
  if(q.audio)
    new Audio(q.audio).play();
  setOutput(q.response(input.val()));
  setTimeout(ask, 5000);
}

function setOutput(txt){
  output.html($('<h1>').text(txt));
}


$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    respond();
    return false;
  }
});

function language () {
  var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
  return userLang
}

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <img src="http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/138/377/fcc.gif" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ffc.gif">
     <h1 class="text-center">Hello I am ZENYATTA!</h1>
     <br> <br>
     <div class="container">
<div class="well">
<div id="output"></div>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Responce:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" value="">
            </div>
        </div>


  

</div>


<!-- jquery for enter key press -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/s.js"> </script>
```